# How would I outset the pixels of an image around transparent areas based on transparency without iterating over every pixel in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

so I would like to take a PIL Image, find non-transparent pixels & make any surrounding transparent pixels the same color of the closest non-transparent pixels.

Preferably this would work for an arbitrary offset amount, although not necessarily. A solution that can only go one pixel away is better than nothing

Solutions would preferably use numpy or PILLOW as I already have those libraries in my project, although any solution using other dependencies downloadable via pip is welcome.

The operation has to run relatively fast, as its going to be used in an interactive application where the user will be waiting for the operation to complete. So I would like not to iterate over each pixel in Python

Im using Python 3.10.2

[image]

Comment: last time I needed something like this, I used opencv's (simple) inpainting.

Comment: I would start with `skimage.morphology.dilation`. Getting the color to dilate as well (in addition to dilating the alpha channel) would require the non-painted areas to either already be the correct color, or you could color all pixels black where the alpha is transparent to begin with, and then dilating the color channels will extend the color into the black areas as well.

Comment: @Aaron good advice :) Unfortunetely the transparent pixels dont have the right color already

Comment: @WillyWonka then take the approach I described...  color all transparent pixels black, and use dilation on the color channels as well.

Comment: How about providing a representative starting image that is not annotated and is actually transparent?

Comment: You could 1. iterate over all pixels; 2. found non-transparent -> skip; 3. found transparent - search pixels around it, and if non-transparent found -> fill into its color. This will give you 1px 'padding'